# excluding angular directive using webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angularjs-directive

I want to exclude an angular directive using webpack.

How can I do that like I put modules into the `whitelist` array in external section of `webpack.config.js`

Comment: In Angular cli, if that directive is not being used, it will not be included in the app's bundle, is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Teebo nope , this not what i want , the directive has been used ,  i want to build ssr and when buiding gets to prerendering ,comes up with this error https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-angular/issues/38

Comment: Oh I see, unfortunately I have not worked with MobX in Angular, sorry about that, good luck tho!